# @react-native-google-signin/google-signin/src/GoogleSignin.js threw an exception null is not an object (evaluating 'RNGoogleSignin.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-signin

I'm implementing GoogleSign using firebase for the firebase project. I installed these three packages:

```
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^11.3.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^6.0.0",
```

Then in my Login.js file I'm importing them as:

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
```

Then inside `function Login(props) {` I've

```
    GoogleSignin.configure({
        webClientId: 'MY_WEB_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    });
```

But as soon as I run I get this error:

> Error: Requiring module
> "node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin/src/GoogleSignin.js",
> which threw an exception: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
> 'RNGoogleSignin.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED')

Answer (score 1):

Please run pod-install and on pod install confirm

```
Installing FirebaseAuth (8.1.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (8.1.0)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (8.1.0)
Installing GTMAppAuth (1.2.2)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.5.0)
Installing GoogleSignIn (5.0.2)
Installing GoogleUtilities 7.4.1
Installing RNFBAuth (12.1.0)
Installing RNFBMessaging (12.1.0)
Installing **RNGoogleSignin** (6.0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using '8.0.0' version downgrading to '7.2.2' did trick for me. Remember to remove `^` against version number like this:

@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "7.2.2"